# Spring LDAP and external login

Tags: java, spring, spring-ldap

Is there a way to determine during the user login to check on which storage should spring to look up to for the user credentials? Currently on the project that I am working on requires the company's employee credentials during login should be looked up on an LDAP Server and while giving the company's clients a login access in which the client's login credentials should be looked up on the database?

Answer (score 1):

Spring security supports out of the box multiple credential storages. Just declare two AuthenticationProviders, one accessing LDAP for employees and the latter accessing the client database. Extract from the `ProviderManager` (default `AuthenticationManager` implementation) javadoc:

> AuthenticationProviders are usually tried in order until one provides a non-null response.

Comment: Is there an existing tutorial or code sample on how to do this on java config?